# Regarding the saving of the current status when garbage collection called

Tags: java, android

I had done the r&d on this part ,but could not able to find the answer for this question

If background Activity was GC by android system, how to save current status
before GC really happend?

Regards
Inder bagga

Comment: I thought the whole point of GC was that you didn't really need to worry about it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anything in your app is being garbage collected, it will have already gone through the `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` methods. There is no way to save it *just* before it's being GCd

If you want to store the status, best to do it in one of those - although the absolute safest place to do it is `onPause()`, as `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` are both killable processes, meaning the methods might not be fully executed - see the Android documentation on [Activity lifecycles](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 2):

Since Java GC doesn't provide any callback mechanism or any hooks on before or after it runs, it won't be possible to do some activity just before GC.

Though say for monitoring purpose you can try to trap current status on fix time intervals, to decide this time interval you may want to validate how in your application GC is happening:

```
jstat -gcutil -t -h5 <pid> 500 5
```

this will give you output something like:

```
Timestamp         S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT

         3995.4   0.00   0.00   5.15   0.26  56.95      6    0.019     2    0.057    0.076

         4000.4   0.00   0.00   5.15   0.26  56.95      6    0.019     2    0.057    0.076
```

where YGCT is minor cycle time in millis, this would give a general idea of your application GC stat say minor cycle happens at every 19seconds, based on this you might tune when you want to save current status